# Cant install Ruby on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ruby

Can't install Ruby via

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full
```

The following packages have unmet dependencies :
Ruby, ruby-dev, libtcltk-ruby,  ri

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

```
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
~
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install ruby-full ruby ruby-dev libtcltk-ruby ri`.

Comment: Hmm.  Did you do a `sudo apt-get update` before trying your installation?

Comment: Yes, I did, update and upgrade.

Comment: Ok, try a `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Ahhh!  Try `sudo apt-get purge ruby ruby-dev libtcltk-ruby ri`.  This will remove those packages and remove their configuration files.  Then do your `sudo apt-get install ruby-full`.

Comment: Made a typo above - it's libtcltk-ruby, not litcltk-ruby.  Sorry!

Comment: Package 'ruby' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ruby-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libtcltk-ruby' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ri' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Hmmm...  Does a `sudo dpkg --configure -a` help?

Comment: It did nothing.

Comment: I believe it is just `sudo apt install ruby` for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Terinal recomended the same, but Error E: Package 'ruby' has no installation candidate

Comment: Could you include the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` in your question, please?

Comment: Ok, that looks ok.  Let's see what packages are held: `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`

Comment: It shows nothing.

Comment: Odd, does it still give the "you have held broken packages" if you run `sudo apt-get install ruby-full`?

Comment: Yes it does, maybe I shuld install some older version of Ubuntu...

Comment: @Zhirayr Strange.  I have a package called "ruby".  In fact, this web page indicates that such a package exist in Xenial:  http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ruby .  Do you have the package "ruby2.3"?  http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ruby2.3

Comment: Can you install the package aptitude?  After that, if you do "sudo aptitude update; sudo aptitude search ruby", a list of packages with "ruby" in them should show up.  Anything there look reasonable?

Comment: Actually, in your sources.list, I don't see "main".  Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: I can't install Aptitude same error as with Ruby.

Comment: Wait, I'm going to put a potential answer on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the first lines from your /etc/apt/sources.list file.  Put them in manually at the start of your file:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
```

I know this looks a little funny, but I'd say that's what's lacking in your file.  Copy and paste these to the top of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run `sudo apt-get update` and then try your install.

Comment: Well, the "am" version instead of the "ca" version of the above to match the poster's other archives.

Comment: anonymous2, ubfan1, Terrance, Ray Thank you very much. It worked, I've installed ubuntu from scratch, and didn't change anything, I don't even know why these sources have been missing. Thank you for help.

Answer (score -1):

Using `rbenv` with ruby-build plugin typing:

```
$ rbenv install 2.x.x
```

For installing `rbenv`, see instructions at [GitHub Project's page](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

See also the [ruby-build project page](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#readme).